# Custom setter for copy property in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, setter

Should I have to manually copy object in custom setter with copy property in objective-c?
For example,

I have a property:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *someString;
```

and custom setter:

```
- (void)setSomeString:(NSString *)someString
{
  //option 1
  _someString = someString;
  //option 2
  _someString = [someString copy];
  //do other stuff
}
```

Is it option 1 enough for custom setter or I have to use option 2 instead in order to have copied object?

Comment: What's the *point* of declaring a property with `copy` if you don't make a local copy of the incoming value in your setter??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do whatever you like but you should use the second option.
This is because it will be something like code documentation if other developer see it he or she will know that you copy the string just by looking at:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *someString;
```

The same if you use retain/assign it's best practice to retain/assign object in custom setter. It will make your code more clearer more documented and much more understandable for others developers.

Comment: So in custom setter only I am responsable for setting instance variable? Any automated operations will be omitted?

Comment: Yes and no, you create custom setter if you want to do something more that just set up ivar. Why do you want to create custom setter and put the code which can be done by compiler. You should do your custom stuff you want to do and assign/retain/copy the variable if needed.

Comment: Yes, I need to do some other stuff like after getting a copy of string change a text of label. Thank you!

Comment: It's worth noting in ARC land, you don't need to do anything special if you declare your property as strong, weak or unsafe_unretained. The backing instance variable will automatically have this property (unless you don't have a backing instance variable due to overriding both the setter and getter, in that instance you need to ensure you comply with what you've declared). In all cases though for copy, you should perform a copy yourself, as this isn't something a backing instance variable declaration can do for you (it'd be declared as strong).

Answer (score 1):

You Must use "option 2" because you are using "copy" for your property and statement :

```
_someString = [someString copy];
```

would create a new object in memory and assign it to your property object.

Answer (score 1):

If you write your own custom setter, then you are 100% responsible for everything it does. In your case, you are 100% responsible for the bug that you introduce with option 1 of your code: If I set someObject.someString to a mutable string and change the string later, then the string in your object will change which is most definitely not what you expect from a copy property.

In addition, if you have both a custom setter and getter (or a custom getter for a read-only property) so there is no compiler generated getter or setter, the compiler doesn't create the instance variable for you; you'll have to do that yourself.

You should also notice that "copy" of immutable objects doesn't actually copy them but just retains them, so usually the "copy" operation is really cheap, and when I pass a mutable object, "copy" was most likely what you wanted anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Go with option 2 if you want to make own setter but don't forget to add the condition before the statement like...

```
if(_someString) {
    [_someString release]; 
}
```

Note:- In case of ARC use statement "`_someString = nil`" instead 
of "`[_someString release]`";

Comment: With ARC, _someString = [someString copy] is enough. Without ARC, the code you wrote is dangerous in case I set object.someString = object.someString and there are no other references to the string. someString would be released before it can be copied.

Comment: This is what I want to do. Just releasing the object before copying. Otherwise every time memory allocation will be done after each time setter would be called.